# Erro 242 ao consumir NfeDownloadNF

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, nfe

Estou tentando consumir o serviço de download de NFE na fazenda:

`https://www.sefazvirtual.fazenda.gov.br/NfeDownloadNF/NfeDownloadNF.asmx`

mas tenho obtido o seguinte erro:

> ERRO: 242
>   Motivo: Rejeicao: Elemento nfeCabecMsg inexistente no SOAP Header

```xml
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
    <soap:Body>
        <nfeDownloadNFResult xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF\">
            <retDownloadNFe versao=\"1.00\" xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\">
                <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
                <verAplic>SVAN_2.1.1</verAplic>
                <cStat>242</cStat>
                <xMotivo>Rejeicao: Elemento nfeCabecMsg inexistente no SOAP Header</xMotivo>
                <dhResp>2015-11-03T12:18:06</dhResp>
            </retDownloadNFe>
        </nfeDownloadNFResult>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

O erro é peculiar porque conforme é possível observar na mensagem abaixo a estrutura do cabeçalho está na mensagem.

A mensagem que tenho enviado é :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/nfeDownloadNF">
            <cUF>31</cUF>
            <versaoDados>3.10</versaoDados>
        </nfeCabecMsg>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF">
            <downloadNFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10">
                <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
                <xServ>DOWNLOAD NFE</xServ>
                <CNPJ>[NUMERO DO CNPJ]</CNPJ>
                <chNFe>[CHAVE DA NOTA FISCAL]</chNFe>
            </downloadNFe>
        </nfeDadosMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Removi todos os espaços conforme é solicitado (já consumo alguns outros serviços com sucesso)

```
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
```

O certificado tenho certeza que está correto também.

Ressalto que consigo consumir outros serviços.

WSDL do serviço

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF">
    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF">
            <s:element name="nfeDadosMsg">
                <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="nfeDownloadNFResult">
                <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="nfeCabecMsg" type="tns:nfeCabecMsg"/>
            <s:complexType name="nfeCabecMsg">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="versaoDados" type="s:string"/>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cUF" type="s:string"/>
                </s:sequence>
                <s:anyAttribute/>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="nfeDownloadNFSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="nfeDadosMsg" element="tns:nfeDadosMsg"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="nfeDownloadNFSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="nfeDownloadNFResult" element="tns:nfeDownloadNFResult"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="nfeDownloadNFnfeCabecMsg">
        <wsdl:part name="nfeCabecMsg" element="tns:nfeCabecMsg"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="NfeDownloadNFSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="nfeDownloadNF">
            <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
                Serviço destinado ao atendimento de solicitações de download de Notas Fiscais Eletrônicas por seus destinatários.
            </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:nfeDownloadNFSoapIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:nfeDownloadNFSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="NfeDownloadNFSoap" type="tns:NfeDownloadNFSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="nfeDownloadNF">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF/nfeDownloadNF" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="tns:nfeDownloadNFnfeCabecMsg" part="nfeCabecMsg" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="NfeDownloadNFSoap12" type="tns:NfeDownloadNFSoap">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="nfeDownloadNF">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF/nfeDownloadNF" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:nfeDownloadNFnfeCabecMsg" part="nfeCabecMsg" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="NfeDownloadNF">
        <wsdl:port name="NfeDownloadNFSoap" binding="tns:NfeDownloadNFSoap">
            <soap:address location="https://www.sefazvirtual.fazenda.gov.br/NfeDownloadNF/NfeDownloadNF.asmx"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="NfeDownloadNFSoap12" binding="tns:NfeDownloadNFSoap12">
            <soap12:address location="https://www.sefazvirtual.fazenda.gov.br/NfeDownloadNF/NfeDownloadNF.asmx"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

INFORMAÇÃO NA DOCUMENTAÇÃO DO SERVIÇO

```
POST /NfeDownloadNF/NfeDownloadNF.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.sefazvirtual.fazenda.gov.br
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF/nfeDownloadNF"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF">
      <versaoDados>string</versaoDados>
      <cUF>string</cUF>
    </nfeCabecMsg>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF">xml</nfeDadosMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Alguém poderia me indicar o erro?

Comment: Esse web service é de onde, especificamente? [Procure aqui e não achei](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/webservices.aspx).

Comment: Este é um dos Webservices do SPED, especificamente o serviço responsável por baixar uma nota fiscal especifica pela chave.

Comment: Então, tentei conseguir o WSDL pra conferir se sua mensagem está correta, mas não consegui. De qual site você pegou esse link?

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo ajuda. O link eu peguei em alguns exemplos pela web, mas o WSDL pode ser obtido no endereço :
https://www.sefazvirtual.fazenda.gov.br/NfeDownloadNF/NfeDownloadNF.asmx?wsdl

Todavia se você não conseguir acessar, pode ser alguma restrição quanto a certificados que devem estar instalados no browser

Vou copiar abaixo o conteúdo

Comment: Foi isso que tentei. Deu erro 403. Não faz sentido exigir um certificado para conseguir a WSDL.

Comment: Realmente não faz nenhum sentido, mas parece que é isso que eles fazem.... :( todavia copiei o conteúdo da pagina com o WSDL para minha pergunta.

Comment: Olhando, sem testar, a única coisa que vejo de diferente no *header* da SOAP *message* é o *namespace*, que está `http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/nfeDownloadNF` enquanto deveria ser `http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF`.

Comment: Bruno César realmente, o problema não foi resolvido, mas o namespace estava errado. O erro mudou estou tratando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui fazer funcionar, vou relatar aqui todos os problemas que tive para ajudar alguém que esteja na mesma situação.

Nota é melhor usar a URL:
https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NfeDownloadNF/NfeDownloadNF.asmx

A Mensagem deveria ser a seguinte:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF">
            <cUF>31</cUF>
            <versaoDados>1.00</versaoDados>
        </nfeCabecMsg>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF">
            <downloadNFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="1.00">
                <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
                <xServ>DOWNLOAD NFE</xServ>
                <CNPJ>[CNPJ]</CNPJ>
                <chNFe>[CHAVE]</chNFe>
            </downloadNFe>
        </nfeDadosMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As principais pontos são:

- Hoje dia 04/11/2015 o serviço está na versão 1.00, diferente do que é indicado no site da fazenda
- O namespace deveria ser http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeDownloadNF e não http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/nfeDownloadNF
- Não se esqueça de remover os caracteres em branco, a mensagem não pode ter caracteres de formatação.
- Você só vai conseguir fazer download de notas que tenham manifestação do usuário.